# This seems to be right everywgere But I am getting IndexError everytime at the bin_bash line. but with the puts line its running fine

Tags: python, binary, buffer-overflow, index-error

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pwn
import re

gdb_puts = 0x7ffff7a649c0
gdb_system = 0x7ffff7a33440

offset = gdb_puts - gdb_system

elf = pwn.ELF('./vuln') 
p = elf.process()

prompt = p.recv()
print prompt

puts = re.findall('puts: (.*)', prompt)[0]
bin_bash = re.findall('useful_string: (.*)', prompt)[0]

print puts
print bin_bash
```

This gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ape.py", line 17, in <module>
    bin_bash = re.findall('useful_string: (.*)', prompt)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: It's because your regex doesn't match. As there is no sample data in your question, we can't tell you much more.

Comment: What does just `re.findall('useful_string: (.*)', prompt)` return? If it's nothing, then you probably have a regex problem.

Comment: The field "Title" is for a short title only. A full explanation goes in the much larger field.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a list index out of range on `[0]` then the list is empty, and contains no value. You can check if a list has any values in it using `not`, e.g.:

```
my_list = function_that_returns_a_list()
if not my_list:
    print("Your list is empty")
else:
    print(my_list[0])
```

Verify that your `re.findall('useful_string: (.*)', prompt)` isn't returning an empty list.

Comment: You're probably right I've a C code and compiled binary file in the same directory which has "useful_string" let me add my C code so you can have a better look at it.

Comment: I'm attaching the google drive link //https://drive.google.com/open?id=1srPd4dhrwUkhtUPzr5FtW-ikU2ULAeQ7

Comment: I don't know C well enough to see what data that will parse to your Python script. You'll have to make a different question with different tags - I've answered this one as best I can.